# Design patterns vs Frameworks

Tags: design-patterns, frameworks

Can someone illustrate what really is the difference between the two?

Comment: It's a dumb question which obviously helps people and therefore isn't a dumb question ;)

Comment: I don't think it is a dumb question :)

Comment: It is certainly not a dumb question. Frameworks vs libraries is another interesting one.

Comment: As newcomer to JavaScript, should I learn about design patterns or just use frameworks like React, Angular, Vue etc ?

Comment: @vikramvi Those are not mutually exclusive. You can apply design patterns while using frameworks like React and Vue.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Even though they are two very different things, one can argue they **both solve a software architecture problem**

- a design pattern solves many software architecture issues (about creation, behavior, concurrency, ...) with different pre-defined *design*. (design being an [implementation of an architecture topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268497))
- a framework is based on the [**Hollywood Principle**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_Principle) ("Don't call us, we call you"), where you implement some high level requirements as specified, and leave the framework do the rest of the work, calling your implementations.

A key difference is the **scope cohesion**:

- **design pattern have a** ***tight*** **scope**:

  - class design patterns (involves classes)
  - business design patterns  (involves business workflows)
  - application design patterns (involves applications)
- **framework has a** ***large*** **scope**:
  For instance, **[.NET is a framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/default.aspx)** composed of:

  - a language (C#)
  - a runtime environment (CLR)
  - a collection of libraries
    Just develop what you need and let the .Net framework call your classes.

Answer (score 31):

A design pattern is a concept, or a receipt for how to get a specific problem done.

A Framework is code ready for use, usually packaged in a way that makes creating an application much easier.

It does not make sense to explain the differences because they are two totally different things.

Comment: Couldn't help myself: "A design pattern is a hack to overcome a deficiency in the source language. A framework is code ready for use..."

Comment: A framework can contain/use one or more design patterns (and also architectural patterns), but a design pattern cannot contain a framework.

Answer (score 14):

```
|------------------------|
|          (------)      |
|          (ClassA)      |
|          (------)      |
| (-----------)          |
| ((Singleton))          |
| (-----------)          |
|         (---------)    |     
|         ((Factory))    |
|         (---------)    |
|                        |
|                        |
|------------------------|

Legend:
  |---|  Framework
  (---)  Class
  ()     Design Pattern
```

A framework is a set of related classes to perform a certain task. Those classes may or may not implement a certain design pattern.

Comment: Boo for using counting singleton as a design pattern, +1 for nice explanation. :-P

Comment: It is a design pattern, whether it is overused and misused or not. :P Thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 11):

Here is [GOF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612)'s answer:

> Because patterns and frameworks have 
>   some similarities, people often wonder
>   how or even if they differ. They are 
>   different in three major ways:
>
> - Design patterns are more abstract
>     than frameworks. Frameworks can be
>     embodied in code, but only examples
>     of patterns can be embodied in code.
>     A strength of frameworks is that
>     they can be written down in
>     programming languages and not only
>     studied but executed and reused
>     directly. In contrast, the design
>     patterns in this book have to be
>     implemented each time they're used.
>     Design patterns also explain the
>     intent, trade-offs, and consequences
>     of a design.
> - Design patterns are smaller
>     architectural elements than
>     frameworks. A typical framework
>     contains several design patterns,
>     but the reverse is never true.
> - Design patterns are less specialized
>     than frameworks. Frameworks always
>     have a particular application
>     domain. A graphical editor framework
>     might be used in a factory
>     simulation, but it won't be mistaken
>     for a simulation framework. In
>     contrast, the design patterns in
>     this catalog can be used in nearly
>     any kind of application. While more
>     specialized design patterns than
>     ours are certainly possible (say,
>     design patterns for distributed
>     systems or concurrent programming),
>     even these wouldn't dictate an
>     application architecture like a
>     framework would.

Answer (score 8):

A design pattern is a well-established design for tackling a problem. A framework is an actual package of code you use to make building applications easier. Note that a framework can and probably will, make use of design patterns.

Answer (score 6):

From **Object -Oriented Software Development Using Java** by *Xiaoping Jia*:

> Although both design patterns and frameworks are mechanisms used to capyure reusable designs, they are quite different. On the one hand, design patterns are schematic descriptions of reusable designs that are not concrete programs and that are language independent. On the other hand, frameworks are compilable programs written in a specific programming language and often contain abstract classes and interfaces. Design patterns are  the architectural building blocks of frameworks. They help make frameworks extendable and reusable. Frameworks usually contain implementations of many cooperating design patterns.

Answer (score 5):

**Pattern support reuse of software architecture and design**
- Pattern capture the static and dynamic structures and collaboration of successful solution to problem that arise when building application in particular domain

**Framework supports reuse of detail design and code**
- A framework is an integrated set of a component that collaborate to provide a reusable architecture for a family of related application

Together, design patterns and frameworks helps to improve software quality and reduce development time.

Answer (score 3):

A design pattern is a standard solution to a well known (design) problem. For example the Factory pattern, and the Abstract Factory pattern offer a blueprint for implementing designs to overcome common problems with instantiating objects.

A framework on the other hand contains infrastructure which you can use and extend to develop your own solution. For example a model 2 "web application framework" will contain the infrastructure for building web based applications. It will contain the controller, some gui elements and base classes which we can extend to create our model and business logic. Typically it contains plumbing code and interactions which we inherit when we extend from their base classes. Some examples of frameworks are Struts, JSF, Swing Application Framework, JUnit testing framework, etc...

Going a step ahead there are also libraries, which we use directly from our code. Usually without extending their classes. Log4J would be an example of a library.

Answer (score 0):

Frameworks are more specific to a problem definition. In order to write one design patterns can be devised or used where ever applicable.

Answer (score 0):

answer is very easy:
**framework**: how elements of a system such as (component, layers, class ,...) must or should interact with each other

**design pattern**: a solution for a high frequence problem. it may be an transformation of MSSQL source code to oracle, ........   and have 3 type: analyse, design and implement patterns.

Answer (score 0):

**Pattern**: Set of guild-lines, architecturing the application.

**Framework**: To follow particular pattern, set of pre-build classes and libraries to create architecture pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered a few different ways, though I think a concrete example is missing.

**Design Pattern**: A set of rules put together to solve a *reoccurring problem*. The rules define the pattern. There is no code you can copy paste to implement this. The developer is supposed to understand the rules then implement them.

Example:

- Name: Test Driven Development (TDD)
- Problem: It ensures that the unit tests written cover enough case scenarios that gives you confidence in your production code.
- Rules: It states that you should write your tests first, then write your code after to pass those tests. This then ensures you're not writing tests to pass your code, but instead writing code to pass your tests.

Design Patterns are split into 3 categories:

- Creational Design Patterns:
- Structural
- Behavioral

I've found [this link](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns) to be helpful in explaining them.

---

**Framework**: A framework, not to be confused with libraries, is the basic structure underlying a system that allows developers to build and deploy software applications in a standardized way.

Example: The .Net Core framework is a tool that contains a set of libraries that enables developers using the Microsoft stack to write software applications that can be deployed in multiple different environments (Windows, Mac OS, Linux)

---

**Library**: A reusable set of methods/classes put together in one package to provide functionality.

Example: The [System.Collections.dll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections?view=netframework-4.7.2) library enables .Net developers to use things such as a [Hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable?view=netframework-4.7.2).

---

It's worth it to also look at other answers, as sometimes it's just a buzzword and it differs from one environment to another. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148747/what-is-the-difference-between-a-framework-and-a-library).

I hope this helps.